# Reinstalling Anaconda results in old packages being downloaded

Tags: anaconda

Can never do a clean reset of the conda base environment. Would like to get rid of all user installed packages, but reinstalling Anaconda just downloads the old packages back.

Hi. I have been trying my best to do a clean "reset" of my base environment on Anaconda since it has been becoming quite bloated with packages that I do not use.

I followed the uninstallation instructions on the Anaconda Website.

1.

```
conda install anaconda-clean
```

2. 

```
anaconda-clean --yes
```

I then did a simple remove by removing the anaconda directories through

```
rm -rf anaconda3
```

I then proceeded to remove all traces of anaconda from my ._bash_profile and .zprofile. I also made sure to remove the backup .anaconda folders along with any other folders through

```
rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum
```

However, every time i reinstalled anaconda through the graphic installer, my base environment still features old packages that I downloaded in the past. Could there be a cache that the anaconda installer is accessing to download these old packages? I tried other solutions such as installing old revisions of conda but to no avail. Can someone please tell me how to COMPLETELY wipe out any traces of anaconda such that when I reinstall anaconda, it only comes with the pre-installed packages?

Comment: Please show evidence of what you are talking about. E.g., show `conda list`. Are you sure the "old packages" aren't Pip-installed packages in user site that are leaking in?

Comment: Share some screenshots